# NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog - trying to create a wrapper service for MatDialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am new to coding and new to Angular so I thought I would ask for some help. This is my first question so please be patient with me.

I want to create a wrapper service for the Angular Material Dialog Service (I'm just trying to teach myself - this isn't for a production app) so I made a service in my app like so:

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material';
    
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MatDialogWrapperService {
    
    constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {
    }
    
    open(componentRef, config = {}) {
        this.dialog.open(componentRef, config);
    }
}
```

Now I try to add this to another angular component in my app like so: I import it, add it to the providers array, put it in the constructor and then place it in a method (I have removed some of the code for ease of reading)

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-intro-form',
    templateUrl: './intro-form.component.html',
    providers: [MatDialogWrapperService],
        styleUrls: ['./intro-form.component.scss']
})
export class IntroFormComponent {  
  
    constructor(private modalService: MatDialogWrapperService ) {
    }
    
    modalCall() {
        this.modalService.open(ModalFormComponent, {width: '500px'});
    }
}
```

When I load my app I see the following error in the console:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[
> MatDialogWrapperService -> MatDialog]:  StaticInjectorError(Platform:
> core)[ MatDialogWrapperService -> MatDialog]:
>
> NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog! ; Zone:  ; Task:
> Promise.then ; Value: Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[
> MatDialogWrapperService -> MatDialog]:  StaticInjectorError(Platform:
> core)[ MatDialogWrapperService -> MatDialog]:

I thought I had injected the MatDialog correctly in my wrapper service? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add the `MatDialogModule` to your module imports ?

Comment: @chiril.sarajiu - Facepalm.... thank you! That was my mistake!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This error means you haven't included the Material Dialog module in your application, so there is no provider.

In your `app.module.ts`, ensure you have added `MatDialogModule` to your imports.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    MatDialogModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

For future reference, you need to include the module for **any** Material component you are using. Check the documentation for each to find out which module you need (although most are self explanatory)

Answer (score 12):

For future reference: if someone stumbles upon this question while testing, add `MatDialogModule` to the test imports.

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      MatDialogModule,
    ],
...
```

Comment: Dude you rock! 
As an angular noob on the job, this helped me out big time!

Answer (score 1):

I got an error like you. I don't have modules in my Angular 15 app. I resolved this error this way (add `MatDialogModule` in my main.ts):

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
provideRouter(routes),
{
  //injection token
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: AdminAuthInterceptor,
  //implemented array  of interceptors
  multi: true,
  importProvidersFrom([BrowserAnimationsModule, HttpClientModule, 
  MatDialogModule]),
],
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```