# How can I avoid code repetition/boilerplate when using MatDialog?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm working on an Angular project that uses `MatDialog`s in multiple components. This results in a lot of repeated code which would be a pain to update later on. An example of a component that uses a `MatDialog`:

```js
@Component({
  imports: [
    MatDialogModule,
    PopupComponent
  ]
  ...
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(
    ... 
    private dialog: MatDialog
    ) {  }

    openPopup(data: DialogData): void {
      this.dialog.open(PopupComponent, {
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        data: data,
      });
    }
}
```

The `openPopup` behavior would have to be implemented by every component that uses a popup.

`PopupComponent` would look like:

```js
@Component({
  imports: [CommonModule, MatDialogModule, MatButtonModule],
  ...
})
export class PopupComponent{
  constructor(
    private ref: MatDialogRef<PopupComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData,
  ) {}
    ...
  close() {
    this.ref.close();
  }
}
```

So, from what I understand, an instance of `MatDialog` is being created by `SomeComponent` into a `PopupComponent`, which is then responsible for manipulating the `MatDialog`'s ref (correct me if I'm wrong).

### The actual question:

What I want to know is, what's the best way to abstract the behavior inside `SomeComponent`?

I've tried to simply move the `openPopup` behavior into `PopupComponent`, but that results in a `NullInjection` error in the first parameter of `this.dialog.open`, which I do understand but don't see how to solve in this specific situation.

I've also seen suggestions to use a wrapper service [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54903117/nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-matdialog-trying-to-create-a-wrapper-servic), but that question is from 4 years ago. Is there a better way to do this, or should I go with a Service?

Comment: Hi Tuma, as phrased this question is opinion-based (e.g. "best way to X"), however it should be fairly straightforward to answer objectively if you rephrase the question to ask instead how to solve the actual error you are encountering with the code you tried.

Answer (score 1):

MatDialog instance is created by dependency injector of angular which by defaults makes this a singleton to be used in any component not only in someComponent. this MatDialog generally is used to create a dialog from any components and attach it to the dom.

**answer to the question**

depending on the specific use case you have you can do one of the following.

1. create a directive which contains the functionality of opening the dialog
2. create a service which contains the functionality of opening the dialog

first approach direcive:

```
@Directive({
selector="[openPopup]"
})
export class OpenPopupDirective {

@HostListener('click') openPopUp(): void {
    this.dialog.open(PopupComponent, {
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
      });
}
constructor(
    ... 
    private dialog: MatDialog
    ) {  }

}
```

second approach service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OpenPopupService {

openPopUp(): void {
    this.dialog.open(PopupComponent, {
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
      });
}
constructor(
    ... 
    private dialog: MatDialog
    ) {  }

}
```